# Python: should I subclass threading.Thread?

Tags: python, multithreading

Python's `threading` module has two interfaces. In one you instantiate `threading.Thread` and pass to it the function you want to run, schematically:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.my_vars = {}

    def my_func(self):
        # does stuff
        self.my_vars = # set result of running the function here

mc = MyClass()
t = threading.Thread(target=mc.my_func) # also, pass arguments
# set some options to t, like t.setDaemon(True)
t.start()
```

In the other you subclass `threading.Thread` and subclass the `run` method, schematically:

```
class MyClass(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyClass,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.my_vars = {}

    def run(self):
        # does stuff
        self.my_vars = # set result of running the function here

t = MyThreadedClass()
t.start()
```

I started out using the first one, but at some point realized that I was having to write a lot of boilerplate every time I wanted to start a thread to run `my_func`: I kept having to remind myself the syntax to pass argments to `my_func`, plus I had to write multiple lines to set thread options etc etc. So I decided to move to the second style. In this way I just instantiate my class and then call `.start()`. Note that at this stage the difference is only in how easy it is to use these things, as `my_func` and `run` are exactly the same.

But now I'm realizing that this made my code harder to test. Before if I wanted to test `my_func` under so and so arguments, I just had to `import` the file where it is defined and then run it on some input. Or I could even do it from a jupyter notebook and play it its inputs to see its outputs. But with the second style, every time I want to do something as simple as run `my_func`, it comes with a thread attached.

So question: is there a way I can organize my code that it's cleaner for an application to run it on its own thread, but that has no thread when I want to call it for example from a notebook?

Answer (score 1):

Make objects of your class callable:

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod
import threading

class Callable:
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta

    @abstractmethod
    def __call__(self): raise NotImplementedError

class MyCallable(Callable):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

    def __call__(self):
        print('x=', self.x)


# without a thread:
callable = MyCallable(7)
callable()

# on a thread:
callableThread = threading.Thread(target=callable)
callableThread.start()
callableThread.join()
```

You can do without the formality of using abstract base classes and abstract methods -- just make sure your class defines a `__call__` method that does the work you need to do currently being done by your `my_func`.

Comment: Thanks for responding, please see the edit at the bottom

Comment: There isn't any *one* correct answer, so people will have different opinions -- they are called solutions. I think it was hasty to have closed this question.